# Add 2 dictionary with tuple keys and multiple values

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, sum, tuples

I tried creating a 1D array of a grid point with values of x, and y as a list and then formed a dictionary to make a complete grid with some values stored w.r.t. each key (grid point x,y), in this case, (Vx, Vy,1).
I am trying to add two dictionaries but while I am using the below method dictionary is getting appended instead of getting a sum of values. I tried using the counter as well but that seems to give the error "'>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'". If there is any other more efficient way to add the values of the same keys please mention it.

***Edit :-*** *For sake of simplicity, I am adding here same grid but in actuality there will be two different grids with different keys and values stored in dictionary. I wanted method to add values for same keys.*

```
  #Define the lower and upper limits for x and y
minX = -1
maxX = 1
minY = -1
maxY = 1
#Spac=Spacing Between gridpoints
Spac = 1

cordinates = {(x,y): [] for x in np.linspace(minX, maxX, XSpac) for y in np.linspace(minY, maxY, YSpac)}
grid={(x,y): [Vx,Vy,1] for (x,y) in cordinates}
print(grid)    
pprint(grid)

   for key in grid:
        if key in grid:
            grid2[key] = grid[key] + grid[key]
        else:
            pass
    print(grid2)         
    pprint(grid2)
```

---

```
>>>grid
>>>    {(-1.0, -1.0): [1, 1, 1],
     (-1.0, 0.0): [1, 1, 1],
     (-1.0, 1.0): [1, 1, 1],
     (0.0, -1.0): [1, 1, 1],
     (0.0, 0.0): [1, 1, 1],
     (0.0, 1.0): [1, 1, 1],
     (1.0, -1.0): [1, 1, 1],
     (1.0, 0.0): [1, 1, 1],
     (1.0, 1.0): [1, 1, 1]}
```

---

```
  >>> grid2
  >>>   {(-1.0, -1.0): [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
         (-1.0, 0.0): [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
         (-1.0, 1.0): [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
         (0.0, -1.0): [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
         (0.0, 0.0): [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
         (0.0, 1.0): [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
         (1.0, -1.0): [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
         (1.0, 0.0): [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
         (1.0, 1.0): [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
```

Desired output is

```
 >>>    {(-1.0, -1.0): [2, 2, 2],
     (-1.0, 0.0): [2, 2, 2],
     (-1.0, 1.0): [2, 2, 2],
     (0.0, -1.0): [2, 2, 2],
     (0.0, 0.0): [2, 2, 2],
     (0.0, 1.0): [2, 2, 2],
     (1.0, -1.0): [2, 2, 2],
     (1.0, 0.0): [2, 2, 2],
     (1.0, 1.0): [2, 2, 2]}
```

Comment: Don't you just concatenate list `grid[key]` with itself? If you want to add it to itself elementwise, you should store the coordinates a a numpy array: `{(x,y): np.array([Vx,Vy,1]) for (x,y) in cordinates}`

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I should have mentioned it in the query. I will make an edit. Actually, I will be adding two different grids just for sake of simplicity here I added the same grid. My objective is to add two grids that will be completely different and I have to first check for their coordinates (keys) and then add their values present in the dictionary.